# Make several copies of an animated object

Tags: animation

maybe it's a stupid question, but I want to make a copy of an animated object that coresponds to its position and deformation every 10 frames, for instance. Like a blown by the wind curtain, a mesh when it is still another when it is moving, like making a stop motion animation, but with trails. I don't know if I'm clear. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Please add a screenshot/sketch and/or a link to a video how it should look like

Comment: something like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3K3R.gif

Comment: Actualy, like Dupli-Kate from Invencible, or something like that haha
https://imgur.com/kAfDTaj
You have the animation of a character, bu you want to have a copy of the mesh each x frames. Like its leaving a trail of copies of himself.

Comment: I know how I'd go about doing this, but not while only using Blender. If you export your animation as a png sequence with a transparent background, you can then pull it into After Effects to (either manually or using effect filters) pull out every nth frame and hold it in place for however long, adjusting for camera/background movement. As this isn't a pure Blender suggestion, I've left it as a comment rather than an Answer as it may not be of use.

Answer (score 1):

the "tedious" way is to just render the animated object with transparent background as image e.g. png.

Then in video editor you do it like this:

[image]

in the lowest insert the whole animation.

and e.g. on 11th frame insert just the 11 frame until the end, on 21th frame insert just 21 png and so on

but i am sure there are more clever ways which aren't so tedious...

Comment: Ow, thanks! It's very usefull, this may work for some issues, but i realy need the 3d models, unfortunately! 
Very greatful for your help!

Comment: And what makes you think that this is not a 3D model?

Comment: On blender 2.8 there was a DupliFrame Function. That's more or like what I want. Even so I have the volumes on that case I don't have all of them in the same time.